# SQL Multiple column index not working with LIKE queries

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-like, database-indexes

Considering a table as below

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    "a" varchar(32),
    "b" varchar(32),
    "c" varchar(32),
    "d" varchar(32)
);
CREATE INDEX  "test_index" ON test USING btree("a", "b", "c");
```

I need execute queries like

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM test 
WHERE a like 'a%' 
and b = 'b' 
and c = 'c'
```

The result of EXPLAIN shows below

```
Aggregate  (cost=10.36..10.37 rows=1 width=0)
  ->  Index Only Scan using test_index on test  (cost=0.14..10.36 rows=1 width=0)
        Index Cond: ((b = 'b'::text) AND (c = 'c'::text))
        Filter: ((a)::text ~~ 'a%'::text)
```

Based on the EXPLAIN result from Postgres, only `b` and `c` is using index. It seems `LIKE 'a%'` only works with single column index.

So, how to increase the query speed for the above query?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`** (**not** just a "simple" explain). [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) or upload the plan to https://explain.depesz.com

Comment: What do you get for `SHOW lc_collate`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The perfect index for that query is:

```
CREATE INDEX ON test (b, c, a varchar_pattern_ops);
```

You need `varchar_pattern_ops` for the `LIKE` condition unless the column uses the `C` (or equivalently `POSIX`) collation. Run `SHOW lc_collate;` to see your default collation.

Your index probably cannot be used because you are using a different collation. Also, `LIKE` conditions cause an index range scan, and all the columns with an equality condition should be in the index *before* the column with the range scan.

Comment: Cool! This index is working. EXPLAIN result is below `Aggregate (cost=8.17..8.18 rows=1 width=0) -> Index Only Scan using test_b_c_a_idx on test (cost=0.14..8.17 rows=1 width=0) Index Cond: ((b = 'b'::text) AND (c = 'c'::text) AND (a ~>=~ 'a'::text) AND (a ~<~ 'b'::text)) Filter: ((a)::text ~~ 'a%'::text) `